# solved - Find column wise max elements from a matrix subject to maximization constraints

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, constraints

I have a *N x N* square matrix `A`  consisting of random positive numbers. I have a function that needs to be maximized (for simplicity, consider it sums all the input) whose inputs are one element from each column of the matrix. The constraint is that the position of each of those inputs should be different. For example with N=5

```
A =
      0.43207      0.53996      0.68063      0.70952       0.6297
       0.9656      0.72609      0.88174      0.50072      0.41381
      0.47571      0.99827     0.061184      0.93099      0.88015
      0.98318      0.42879      0.56813       0.3835    0.0039668
      0.30498      0.30033      0.76003      0.80426      0.84147
best =
     4     3     2     1     5
bestA =
      0.98318      0.99827      0.88174      0.70952      0.84147
```

For now I am checking all possible combinations. But as the matrix size increases, e.g. N=10, search space becomes 10! which too expensive for my requirements. I tried to sort the matrix and look for patterns, but I am stuck in cases where there are repetitions which can be seen in this case after sorting.

```
>> [Asorted,I] = sort(A,1,'descend')
Asorted =
      0.98318      0.99827      0.88174      0.93099      0.88015
       0.9656      0.72609      0.76003      0.80426      0.84147
      0.47571      0.53996      0.68063      0.70952       0.6297
      0.43207      0.42879      0.56813      0.50072      0.41381
      0.30498      0.30033     0.061184       0.3835    0.0039668
I =
     4     3     2     3     3
     2     2     5     5     5
     3     1     1     1     1
     1     4     4     2     2
     5     5     3     4     4
```

Is there any algorithm or any kind of intuition I can follow?

I am using MATLAB, but you can use any popular programming language to explain.

**Edit**: The matrix is already given and it is generated randomly. The main objective is to maximize the output of a given function which i have mentioned above and find what are those inputs for which the output is maximum.

**Edit 2**: A sample MATLAB code for above example

```matlab
N=5;
A = rand(N,N)
combs = perms(1:N);
Sbest = -1;
for i=1:size(combs,1)
    x = combs(i,:);
    S = 0;
    for i=1:N
        S=S + A(x(i),i); 
    end
    if S>Sbest
        Sbest=S; best = x;
    end
end
best
[Asorted,I] = sort(A,1,'descend')
```

**Solution**: As pointed out by @גלעד ברקן in the comments, this can be solved using Hungarian Algorithm. Some resources are [here](http://csclab.murraystate.edu/~bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html), [matlab code](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20652-hungarian-algorithm-for-linear-assignment-problems-v2-3)

Comment: I don't fully understand the question - are you trying to write a function to create such random matrix? or you are given such random matrix, and you want to compute something from it?

Comment: @FangQ I have added the info in the question

Comment: what do you mean by "a  function that needs to be maximized"? maximize what? can you define your object function? I assume the function you provided is for generating the matrix. are you constructing a random matrix that somehow maximize a metric?

Comment: In the case of computing sum of inputs the problem is the gragh [maxflow](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.maxflow.html) algorithm.

Comment: @rahnema1 Thanks. I tried doing it but I am having difficulty converting matrix to graph. Can you show an example?

Comment: @titusarmah99 Sorry, I was wrong. It needs multiple computations of maxflow with different graph permutations that I think isn't a good choice.

Comment: @rahnema1 How about we add two extra nodes, a start node and a target node. Connect start node with at beninging of each different graph and connect their end with target node?

Comment: @titusarmah99 The constraint that  the position of each input should be different disables such a configuration.

Comment: @rahnema1 Aahh!! yes you are right

Comment: Isn't this an instance of the assignment problem, for which we could use the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#The_problem)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Hm, you may be right...

Comment: Ah, taking *all* columns makes it an assignment problem. Selecting a *subset* of columns is set cover.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the algorithm, I suspect it might be necessary to go through all combinations to find the best, i.e., brute force. I am not sure if any graph theory algorithm is straightforwardly applicable to this problem, but perhaps some modified ones could work.

From the aspect of acceleration, maybe you can speed up by replacing the inner `for` loop with `sum`, i.e.,

```
for i=1:size(combs,1)
    x = combs(i,:);
    S = sum(A(((1:N)-1)*N + x));
    if S > Sbest
      Sbest=S; 
      best = x;
    end
end
```

Comment: I also think it is unnecessary to go through all combs. I am asking for an algorithm that does that, if possible. The speeding up you suggested is nice if code stays in MATLAB only, but will be useless in other platform.

Comment: @titusarmah99 I am not sure if `CVX` can help solve this kind of optimization problem. If you know it, maybe you can have a try

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. Although I already have applied some [evolutionary optimization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm). But they are all sub-optimal algorithms. i want some concrete algorithm that always gives best result

Comment: @titusarmah99 Maybe you can try `matchpairs`, which is a built-in function of MATLAB and solves the linear assignment problem

Comment: i am using R2018a, so i dont have it, but thanks anyway. There are lots of implementation out there